# If data source doesn't emit data for a while, does the watermark of Flink operator keep advancing?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

[image: watermark]

Just curious, if the data source doesn't emit data for a while, whether Flink operator still receive watermark or not? the `Low Watermark` in the image will keep advancing or stay still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the watermark will continue to advance when the source is completely idle depends on the `WatermarkStrategy`. Neither of the built-in strategies (i.e., `BoundedOutOfOrderness` or `MonotonousTimestamps`) will advance the watermark under these circumstances, but some folks use custom strategies that detect idleness and advance the watermark based on the passage of wall-clock time.

If some of the source partitions/splits/shards are idle and others are not, then this could lead to the watermark failing to advance. Some sources support a watermark strategy that implements a `withIdleness` option that overcomes this problem [1].

[1] https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#dealing-with-idle-sources

Comment: Does the withIdleness strategy work on connected streams? I am facing a similar issue as reported in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-18934. Is there any workaround for detecting idleness in a connected stream?

Comment: If FLINK-18934 is preventing withIdleness from working for you, you can work around this with a hack, by using a rebalance before watermarking so that the idle stream is blended with non-idle streams, or you can use something like https://github.com/aljoscha/flink/blob/6e4419e550caa0e5b162bc0d2ccc43f6b0b3860f/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/timestamps/ProcessingTimeTrailingBoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor.java to handle the idleness yourself.

Comment: @SairamSankaran did you find any workaround? FLINK-18934 its fixed and released on version 1.14.0, but still doesn't work for me.